# Blank screen on ios 8 caused by malfunctioning routing

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have created an ionic app.
The application works with 'ionic serve' on chrome & safari, as a native app on android and on iphone with ios 9.
The problem occurs when I test it against ios 8. Both on actual phone and emulator.
At a high level the problem is that the ui-router otherwise doen't work properly.
Digging into the source code revealed, the transition promise is getting to the ERROR callback. On working environments the promise is getting to the SUCCESS callback.
The promise is at line 40963 on ionic.bundle.js 1.0.1 source code.

I can't find related issues online. I'll appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.